# value in getPath url

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking

I use AFnetworking to load locations in the first view of my iOS app

```
LocationTableViewController.m

 [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" parameters:nil
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                         NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                                         NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
                                         for (id locationDictionary in response) {
                                             Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
                                             [results addObject:location];

                                         }
                                         self.results = results;
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];
                                     }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                     }];
```

The response from the api is

```
 {

        "created_at" = "2013-02-23T19:17:37Z";
        id = 1;
        lat = "51.463842";
        long = "-0.6504559999999628";
        name = Legoland;
        "street_address" = "Winkfield Road, Windsor, United Kingdom";
        "updated_at" = "2013-02-23T19:17:37Z";
    },
```

I display the name and street_address

[image]

When a user clicks on a location the iOS app segues to the BeerTableViewController. I would like to retrieve the clicked on locations beer list using something like this request.

```
BeerTableViewController.m

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"locations/%@/beers.json",
    [dictionary objectForKey:@"location_id"]];


  [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:path parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                                            NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
                                            for (id beerDictionary in response) {
                                                Beer *beer = [[Beer alloc] initWithDictionary:beerDictionary];
                                                [results addObject:beer];

                                            }
                                            self.results = results;
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error fetching beers!");
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                        }];
```

I'm not sure how to pass the location_id value from the LocationTableViewController cell when a user clicks it so that it fills the getPath url with the appropriate value. Clicking on location 1 would set the getPath url in BeerTableViewController to `@"locations/1/beers.json`

The response I get back from this request is

```
{
        "created_at" = "2013-02-23T19:27:10Z";
        description = Awesome;
        id = 2;
        "location_id" = 1;
        name = Pliny the Elder;
        price = "3.50";
        style = IPA;
        "updated_at" = "2013-02-23T19:27:10Z";
    }
```

Right now I just get errors `Unknown receiver 'dictionary' No known class method for selector 'objectForKey'` in my BeerTableViewController.m request

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"locations/%@/beers.json",
        [dictionary objectForKey:@"location_id"]];
```

Should I be setting this up in

```
LocationTableViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I think it's telling you it can't find anything named "dictionary" within the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"locations/%@/beers.json",
    [dictionary objectForKey:@"location_id"]];

[[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:path //....
```

Comment: When I added that I got a couple of errors, unknown receiver 'dictionary' and no known class method for selector 'objectForKey' current code pasted in next comment.

Comment: NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"locations/%@/beers.json",
                      [dictionary objectForKey:@"location_id"]];
    
    [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations/@location_id/beers.json" parameters:nil

Comment: @JacobTimm I think @danh was a bit confused; his answer used a dictionary as it might have been passed to your `-initWithDictionary:` method in `Location.m`. Do you have an instance of `Location` available in the scope your `getPath` method is called? If you do (and let's assume it's called `myLocation`), then simply substitute `[myLocation location_id]` for `[dictionary objectForKey:@"location_id"]` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @trudyscousin thanks for clarifying. I'm new to iOS dev and actually not sure if I have an instance of Location available in the scope my getPath method is called. Can you point me in the right direction for creating that myLocation instance? Thanks.

Comment: @JacobTimm Do remember that my use of the name `myLocation` was just an example. Anyway, part of the answer already lies in your initial question: You get it from calling -[Location initWithDictionary:] when your user taps. Do you retain that resulting `Location` instance anywhere? If you do, can you communicate it to where you're calling `-[LocationApiClient getPath:parameters:success:]`?

Comment: @trudyscousin I don't believe that I am currently retaining the resulting Location instance anywhere after calling -[Location initWithDictionary:  How would I do that?

Comment: @trudyscousin I revised my original question above. Any chance you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @danh ended up having the right answer after I sorted out some other issues that were not setup correctly. Thanks.